"Automatic Boot Assessment" for SLES, RHEL, how to implement it in reality?

https://blog.koehntopp.info/2024/07/22/crowdstroke.html
->
So, if you ask me what my takeaway from the Crowdstrike issue is, I’d
say: boot counting/boot assessment/automatic fallback should really be
a MUST for today’s systems. Before* you invoke your first kernel you
need have tracking of boot attempts and a logic for falling back to
older versions automatically. It’s a major shortcoming that this is
not default behaviour of today’s distros, in particular commercial
ones.
Of course systemd has supported this for a long time: Automatic Boot
Assessment
Windows does not do that, but Linux could. If commercial Linux distros
were to use this feature.
->
https://systemd.io/AUTOMATIC_BOOT_ASSESSMENT/

->
Question: can anybody write a very short step-by-step howto, how to enable the feature on SLES and RHEL that if boot fails, it would automatically boot with an older kernel? This looks like a so rarely used feature of systemd that there aren't any good howtos in the internet for it to be more widespread.

Seeing as neither rhel nor sles uses systemd-boot, this is probably in vein

Grub can supposedly do something similar, that should work on RHEL at least (but I’ve never tried it).
